# GeoDjango: Extending GeoManager with Search Functionality

Tags: python, django, geodjango, django-managers

I am learning to use GeoDjango, and it is my understanding that a GeoManager() is needed to interact with GIS objects.

However, I was trying to build in some search functionality for my models. I found this [old post](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/09/quick-dirty-search-django/) that showed how to build a nifty little search manager using q objects like so:

```
class NewsPostManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, search_terms):
        terms = [term.strip() for term in search_terms.split()]
        q_objects = []

        for term in terms:
            q_objects.append(Q(title__icontains=term))
            q_objects.append(Q(content__icontains=term))

        # Start with a bare QuerySet
        qs = self.get_query_set()

        # Use operator's or_ to string together all of your Q objects.
        return qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
```

It is my understanding that this wouldn't work for GIS objects, as it doesn't invoke models.GeoManager(). Is there a way to extend models.GeoManager with this added functionality?

Comment: I havent tested this, but have you tried subclassing models.GeoManager instead of models.Manager?

Comment: That's a great thought! I will try and figure out how to modernize this code and see if it works.

Comment: It works! Thank you :) Please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [extra manager methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods). In the case of geodjango you have to override the default manager (objects) with a [GeoManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geomanager).
You need to override models.GeoManager instead of models.Manager to have a custom manager on that case.